# Junk perl code generator for obfuscation

Tags: perl, obfuscation

Having a code:

```
Line1 
Line2
..
LineN
```

I want to automatically produce

```
Line1
JunkLines2-100
Line2
JunkLines102-200
Line3
  etc.
```

where JunkLines are Perl junk code that does not change state of program but looks like continuation of legitimate program.

I don't want obfuscate my code with obfuscators that, say, rename variable names to something unreadable - this unreadability is a signal that code is obfuscated.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? It's easy enough to write illegible and horrible perl code without trying to obfuscate it... typically doing so is deemed bad programming style, and so isn't really something that users of this site are keen to promote.

Comment: I'm trying to uglify some beautiful code by augmenting it with junk code that does nothing except lurking a reverse engineer into debugging and time waste. It's like a labyrinth: you have only one (maybe more) path to exit it and much more paths leading to dead end; it's a purpose of labyrinth to make traveler (reverse engineer) to waste its time on debugging dead-end paths. It's obvious I think.

Comment: If `perl -MO=Deparse` didn't exist, maybe.

Comment: Well, maybe analogy from 0x86 be helpful:

Obfuscator features
Features list:
changing code execution flow (non linear code path) - it's usefull against all kinds of debuggers, analysis of such code is very "unpleasant"
mutation of original instructions into series of other equivalent opcodes - obfuscator can mutate both arithmetic and logical opcodes
inserting garbage opcodes between real instructions (so called "junks")
inserting fake instructions between real ones, 32/16/8 opcodes are generated

Comment: That's of http://www.pelock.com/products/obfuscator

Comment: Whilst cute, simply doesn't apply to an interpreted language.

Comment: Why not? Reversing 1Kb of assembly or 5Mb of garbaged perl code maybe equally hard, especially if you cannot simply debug perl code, as in case of code running in production on cluster. Actually, you maybe want to remember how bad guys leech inframe trafiic from hacked sites. They usually obfuscate iframe JS, not so?

Comment: Going back to the first comment... "What are you actually trying to accomplish?"  Yeah, yeah, you want to obfuscate code and give imagined reverse engineers the middle finger, but why?  That's a means to an end, not an end unto itself.

Comment: How is this technical problem of obfuscating related to your question "why to give finger"? Strange people, strange answers...

Comment: I think you're deeply missing the `interpreted language` element. In order for perl to run - at all - it compiles it's script at run time. At which point it de-obfuscates what it's doing, because it needs to in order to run it.

Comment: Well, I know that Perl does not care of code obfuscation exactly like CPU does not care of it. Obfuscation is targeted at REVERSE ENGINEER who does get confused of garbage code. As I stressed in my initial question I'm not interested in usual semantics obfuscation like making varnames unreadable but in adding junk code that obfuscate logic of execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why so many downvotes: this looks like an interesting problem.

I had some spare time and tried something on my own:

- Garbage code is in a separate file with blocks separated by #---
- Ofuscator is changing names of variables and functions in garbage code if this exists in original good code (I assumed you define variables with `my` and functions with `sub`)
- Ofusctaor is randomly adding content from garbage file (looping if needed)

That looks like this

**Good code** (original.pl)

```
#!perl
use strict;

my $var1='hello';
my $var2='there';

sub f {
    print "This is a function";
    ++$var1
}

print $var1;
print "\n$var2";
```

**Garbage code** (garbage_code.pl)

```
#!perl
#---
my $var2='__NEW';
my $var3="This is garbage";
#---
sub g {
    $var3+="changed";
    print "This shall be removed";
    return $var3;
}
#---
sub f { 
    return g(shift).$var2;
}
#---
f("function name shall be changed");
```

**Offuscator**

```
#!perl
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

#-Get Original 'good' code
open CODE,"<original.pl" or die $!;
my @code=<CODE>;
close CODE;

#-Get Garbage code
open GARBAGE,"<garbage_code.pl" or die $!;
my @garbage=split(/^#---/m, join("",<GARBAGE>));
shift @garbage; #Remove header
map { s/^.*?(\w.*?)\s*$/\1/s } @garbage; #Trail spaces and EOL at beginning and end
map { s/print .*?;//g } @garbage; #Remove print calls
close GARBAGE;

#-List variables and functions in good code
my %list_var;
my %list_func;
for my $line (@code) {
    if ($line=~/my \s*[\$@%](\w+)/) { $list_var{$1}=undef; }
    elsif ($line=~/sub \s*(\w+)/) { $list_func{$1}=undef; }
    else { }
}

#-List variables and functions in garbage code
my @list_var_garbage;
my @list_func_garbage;
for my $line (@garbage) {
    while ($line=~/my \s*[\$@%](\w+)/g) { push(@list_var_garbage,$1); }
    while ($line=~/sub \s*(\w+)/g) { push(@list_func_garbage,$1); }
}

#-Replace names of variables and functions in garbage code if it exists in good code
#Get equivalent name
for my $type ('var', 'func') {
    my $rh_list = ($type eq 'var' ? \%list_var : \%list_func);
    my @list_names=(keys %$rh_list, ($type eq 'var' ? @list_var_garbage : @list_func_garbage));
    for my $name (@list_names) {
        #Get new name
        my $new_name=$name;
        #For names of good code OR new names in garbage code
        if (!defined $rh_list->{$new_name}) {
            while (exists $rh_list->{$new_name}) { $new_name.="1"; }
            #Store in hash table
            $rh_list->{$new_name}=undef; #to ensure uniqueness of replacements
            $rh_list->{$name}=$new_name; #Replacement name in garbage code
        } else {}
    }
}
#Replace
map { s/(?:sub \s*|&)\K(\w+)/$list_func{$1}/g } @garbage;
map { s/(\w+)\(/$list_func{$1}(/g } @garbage;
map { s/[\$@%]\K(\w+)/$list_var{$1}/g } @garbage;


#-Function to get garbage content
my $i_garbage=0;
sub get_garbage {
    return $garbage[ ($i_garbage++) % scalar(@garbage) ]."\n";
}


#-Copy garbage in good code
my @new_code;
for my $line (@code) {
    #-Add the line
    push(@new_code, $line);

    #-Add garbage
    #Blocks: add garbage at the end
    if ($line=~/\{/ .. $line=~/\}/) {
        if ($line=~/\}/) { push(@new_code, get_garbage());  }
    #Other: randomly add garbage 
    } else {
        if (int(rand(2))) { push(@new_code, get_garbage()); }
    }
}

#Print file with new code
open NEW_CODE, ">new.pl" or die $!;
print NEW_CODE @new_code;
close NEW_CODE;
```

**Result**

```
#!perl
use strict;
my $var21='__NEW';
my $var3="This is garbage";

sub g {
    $var3+="changed";

    return $var3;
}
my $var1='hello';
sub f1 { 
    return g(shift).$var21;
}
my $var2='there';

f1("function name shall be changed");
sub f {
    print "This is a function";
    ++$var1
}
my $var21='__NEW';
my $var3="This is garbage";

sub g {
    $var3+="changed";

    return $var3;
}
print $var1;
print "\n$var2";
sub f1 { 
    return g(shift).$var21;
}

f1("function name shall be changed");
```

It probably does not take into account all cases but this is definitely a good working prototype.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're receiving negative votes from lack of information or what, but this is a relatively easy fix. Assuming you want to do it in Perl:

just create another perl file which reads in your file one line at a time,prints it out to a new file, and appends a line of random nonsense afterwords (in this case, from a large file which is assumed to contain a bunch of random lines of perl code "obfuscatedlines.txt")

A small example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @randomlines;
open (INHANDLE, "<perlfile.pl");
open (OBHANDLE, "obfuscatedlines.txt");
open (OUTHANDLE, ">newfile.pl");
while(<OBHANDLE>) {push @randomlines, $_;}
my $i=0; 
while(<INHANDLE>)
{
    print OUTHANDLE $_;
    print OUTHANDLE $randomlines[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Random lines of perl code can easily screw original file. For example, junk perl file may contain variables of the same name as in original file and change them, which is unacceptable.

Comment: assuming you're writing the junk file yourself that's easily avoidable, but either way there are numerous solutions to that problem. I was only providing a framework for you to build on, not doing your entire problem for you.